# Чому «знімок» і «знимка»

Tags: чергування

Думав використати *знімка* як похідне від *знімок*. Вирішив пошукати в інеті і надибав [*зн**и**мка*](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0).

> **ЗНИМКА — СИНОНІМІЯ**
> знімок
>
> 1. знимка
> 2. світлина *(г.)*
> 3. фото
> 4. фотографія
> 5. фотознімок

Чому тут *і* чергується з *и*?

Цікаво, що [у Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/20799-znymka.html) це взагалі *лестива жінка, підлиза*.

Comment: Додам: [знима́ти, зни́мець](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=зним*&dicts=8&main_only=on&highlight=on).

Answer (score 2):

[-Єм-, -їм-, -(й)м-, -(й)н-, -йом-, -нім- — це форми одного й того самого дуже давнього кореня](/a/2594).

На практиці ходить і варіант -ним-:
винима́ти ,
(по-) віднима́ти  ,
донима́ти ,
(пере-, по-) знима́ти (-ся)  ,
нанима́ти ,
обнима́ти ,
піднима́ти (-ся) ,
понима́ти (-ся) ,
пронима́ти ,
рознима́ти ,
унима́ти (-ся)  .

Тобто, якщо коротко, *зни́мка* походить від не повністю визнаного слова *знима́ти*, яке може виступати синонімом як літературному *здійма́ти*, так і літературному *зніма́ти*.

На цю ж тему: [обговорення на Словник.UA](//slovnyk.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?p=7671).